# How to alter the data type of a column from varchar2 to number in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, types, alter

When I ran the `alter` query, I get error saying that column to be modified must me empty.

```
Table  : Monthly_Result (Id Number(38,0), dealer_ID varchar2, sales_revenue Number(38,2))
```

`dealer_Id` should be changed to Number(38,0)

Please help

Comment: If it has data then you'd have to remove it to make this change with `alter` - which you presumably don't want to do? That's what the message is telling you. You'll have to add a new column, copy/convert the data, drop the old column, and rename the new one. Carefully. And that assumes all the data *will* convert cleanly, Does this change have to be done online?

Answer (score 10):

As Alex mentioned in his comment you will need to add new column; update it and check values were converted correctly; then drop the old column when you're ready.

```
-- step 1
alter table monthly_result add tmp number(38, 0);
update monthly_result set tmp = to_number(dealer_id);

-- step 2
--  check values are set correctly in tmp

-- step 3
alter table monthly_result rename column dealer_id to dealer_id_old;
alter table monthly_result rename column tmp to dealer_id;

-- step 4
alter table monthly_result drop column dealer_id_old;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex and Richard

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it would be help the update add column things you will loss your primary key and position of the table:

--COPY THE DATA TO TEMPORARY TABLE
CREATE TABLE _TMP AS SELECT * FROM ;

--TRUNCATE OLD DATA
TRUNCATE TABLE ;

--ALTER SPECIFIC COLUMN TYPE
alter table  MODIFY  number(38, 0);

--BRING THE DATA FROM WHICH COPY PREVIOUS TEMPORARY TABLE
INSERT INTO  SELECT * FROM _TMP;

--CHECK YOUR DATA
SELECT * FROM ;

--DROP YOUR TEMPORARY TABLE
DROP TABLE _TMP;

I believe it will work for you.